# Check own attachments

Tags: mutt

If I'm writing an email and add some attachments I want to test, if they are really correct. The problem is, that I don't know how I can open them. For example, if I have the following:

[image]

So this is the text from the image:

```
- I     1 /tmp/neomutt-TORNAX-ARCH-1000-72152-1367        [text/plain, 7bit, us-ascii, 0.1K]
  A     2 ~/Screenshot.png                                [image/png, base64, 86K]
```

and I'd like to check, if the image is the correct one, how can I open it? Pressing `v`, gives me the following error message from my image viewer (viewnior):

```
Error when getting information for file "/tmp/-editor_wallpaper.jpg":No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this?

## My settings

My `~/.config/neomutt/neomuttrc` file:

```
# vim: filetype=neomuttrc
# == Global options ==
source ./colorscheme/custom.muttrc

unset record
ignore *
unignore from: date: subject: to: cc: reply-to:

#set use_from=yes
set autoedit
set edit_headers
set header_cache=~/.cache/mutt/headers/
set include
set index_format="%4C %Z %{%Y-%b-%d} %-23.23F|%4c| %s"
set mail_check=60
set message_cachedir=~/.cache/mutt/messages/
set query_command = "abook --mutt-query '%s'"
set sort=threads
set sort_aux=last-date-received
set timeout=15
set pager_stop=true
set postponed="/rest/mails/postponed"
#set pager=nvim
source ./sidebar.muttrc
source ./mappings.muttrc

< accounts >
```

Comment: Check "/tmp/" dirctory, show permissions in file. Do you send this mail from root or the other user?

Comment: @RodrigoCunha I'm sending the mail from my user account (so not from root).

Comment: @RodrigoCunha I took a look into the `/tmp` directory when I was in the compose menu and I couldn't find my `Screenshot.png` there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mutt open files based on MIME type and all types should be listed in mailcap. Obviously your (or default) mailcaps are not aligned to your system.

Check those files to see what command is running against this particular type.

- $HOME/.mailcap
- $PKGDATADIR/mailcap
- $SYSCONFDIR/mailcap
- /etc/mailcap
- /usr/etc/mailcap
- /usr/local/etc/mailcap

my personal .mailcap entry is:

```
image/jpg; mkdir -p /tmp/mutt \; cp %s /tmp/mutt/ \; eog /tmp/mutt/$(basename %s) &
```

You can add it to ~/.mailcap and see what happens (replace eog with your viewer).

If you try to find this file you should know:

- Mutt delete file after command is executed. At the point you look there command was already failed and file was deleted.
- In modern systems /tmp may be separated for different processes, so you have to run `find /tmp -name ....jpg`

Comment: Thank you! It's working now :) Adding the directory and copying the file to it works for me! :)